# SQL Pivot with multiple lines per result

Tags: sql, pivot, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to learn how I can pivot date with Advantage Database Server.

I have the following code which will pivot (using CASE), our monthly sales data:

```
    SELECT YEAR(date) as MyYear
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  1 THEN value END) jan_revenue
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  1 THEN value - (qty*ekp/pe) END) jan_margin
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  2 THEN value END) feb_revenue
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  2 THEN value - (qty*ekp/pe) END) feb_margin
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  3 THEN value END) mar_revenue
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  3 THEN value - (qty*ekp/pe) END) mar_margin
  FROM (SELECT DAB020.*
             , EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM date) year
             , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) month
       FROM "DAB020.ADT" DAB020
          where buart = 'A' and auf_kumsta = 'J' and date >= '2021-01-01'
       ) mysalesdata
 GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

This produces a result looking like this:

```
MyYear  jan_revenue jan_margin  feb_revenue jan_margin_1    mar_revenue jan_margin_2
2021    23123414    12312323    4554535     545345          435345      123123
```

What I really want, is for the revenue and margin to be on different lines:

```
MyYear  TYPE    jan         Feb         Mar 
2021    Revenue 23123414    12312323    4554535    
2021    Margin  545345      435345      123123
```

(numbers are fake-but you get the idea)

How can I do this? I'm sure that a combination of CASE and Grouping is the solution, but I am not able to work it out.

(edit: there is no pivot function in ADS, as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot the data to get the margin and revenue in different rows.  Then aggregate like you are doing now:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as MyYear, type, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  1 THEN value END) as jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  2 THEN value END) as feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  3 THEN value END) as mar
FROM (SELECT DAB020.*
      FROM (SELECT date, 'revenue' as type, value, buart, aufkumsta
            FROM "DAB020.ADT" UNION ALL
            SELECT date, 'margin' as type, value - (qty*ekp/pe), buart, aufkumsta
            FROM "DAB020.ADT"
           ) DAB020
      WHERE buart = 'A' AND auf_kumsta = 'J' AND
            date >= '2021-01-01'
     ) mysalesdata
 GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Comment: thankyou, it works. Very useful... going to decode this and reuse as much as I can!

Comment: once more question if I may: how could I add in a calculation field (margin %) into the results

Comment: @egg . . . You should ask another question for the margin % and be sure to show what the results should look like.